# No counterexamples for convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

If $$X_n\rightarrow 3$$ in probability, then  $$|X_n|\rightarrow 3 $$in probability.

If $$|X_n|\rightarrow 3 $$ in probability, then  $$X_n\rightarrow 3$$ in probability.

I don't think counterexamples exist for these two statements, does that make them both true?

Comment: One of them has a trivial counterexample.  If $x$ is a real number such that $|x|=3$ what do you know about $x$?

Answer (score 2):

The first statement is true. As for the second statement, consider $X_n=3$ with probability 1/2, and $X_n=-3$ with probability 1/2. Then it is not true that $X_n\to 3$ in probability.